# iPhone Health "Walking + Running Distance" is way off

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app, health-kit

The "Walking + Running Distance" on my iPhone 6 is wildly off.

I've walked <2 miles today (0.5 mile commute, 0.8 miles for lunch, and whatever around the office), yet my iPhone is reporting 10.3 miles. It's been way off like this for a while.

Is there any way to troubleshoot what's happening here? Or recalibrate the feature?

Number of steps seems OK...6767 steps at 1.5ft/step would be about 2 miles, which is close to my estimate.

Additionally, I cannot "Show All Data" for any of the health metrics, the loading spinner just keeps spinning.

[image: Health Dashboard]

Answer (score 2):

If you have any 3rd party apps for health tracking, like Withings, they sometimes add onto your records.

My experience was my Withings app completely doubling my steps and distances.  If you do have these apps, delete them or just turn of their accessibility to your health.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing's weird... it says 7k steps but the top line shows 3k, Walk/run again, 10m, but the top line is only 5... & repeat for the flights.
The top line ought to be the next 'sensible' number above the highest single point recorded for that day/week/month.

I'd try at least a reboot if not a restore.
The issue with waiting forever to view the details may be related. I lost about a week of data when mine did that. The dotted lines are a giveaway that it's not reading its own data correctly.

Comment: Yeah, something's definitely not right. It may even be just a bug in of iOS, but at least iOS 9 should be here in a couple of weeks...

Comment: Regarding the scale of the y-axis, I think it's supposed to be Distance/Time (Miles/Hour). The horizontal axis is obviously Time (hours). It makes sense that I peaked at under 5 MPH since I was just walking. The total daily distance should be the area under the 'active' line segments. That's how I made sense of the graph....but the 10mile total still doesn't add up....

Comment: I really don't think it's 'miles per hour' it's 'highest data point plus a reasonable overhead'. In the single data-point I've managed to generate today (going to make my morning coffee;) I've done 136 steps, the peak line shows 150, 0.03m, peak 0.04. If I switch to Week, the peak line is 8k steps, 4 miles, which is about right for my daily average.